# SQL*Plus Scheduled Task Hangs After Connect timeout

Tags: scheduled-tasks, sqlplus

I have a scheduled task that executes a `sqlplus` command, with username and password supplied.

Intermittently there is a `ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred` that occurs. After these happen, `SQL*Plus` asks for a username, which never times out, pausing my task indefinitely.

How can I guard against this? Is there any command line option that can prevent this?

Task batch file

```
...
sqlplus user/\"password\"@database@script.sql  >> "script.log"
```

script.sql

```
START TRANSACTION;
call schema.sync_task();
COMMIT;
quit;
```

successful log

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Sep 10 22:15:00 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Sep 10 2018 22:10:00 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Automatic Storage Management option

SP2-0310: unable to open file "TRANSACTION.sql"

Call completed.

Commit complete.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Automatic Storage Management option
```

failed log

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Sep 10 22:20:00 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred


Enter user-name:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a clean solution, but I did find the simple one.

I've modified the settings of the scheduled task to stop if running longer than an hour. 10 minutes would have been better, but that wasn't an option in the task scheduler.